# Trying to make a video go full screen using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with video thumbnails. When a video is clicked, it opens file `video.html` and passes the video path to it.

I am trying to make `video.html` open the video in full screen but when I say full screen I really mean all screen with no browser visible.

This is the contents of `video.html`

```
<body>

<script>
window.onload=function() {
  let videoDiv = createVideoDiv()

  if (videoDiv.requestFullscreen) {
    videoDiv.requestFullscreen();
  }
  else if (videoDiv.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    videoDiv.mozRequestFullScreen();
  }
  else if (videoDiv.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    videoDiv.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  }
  else if (videoDiv.msRequestFullscreen) {
    videoDiv.msRequestFullscreen();
  }

  document.getElementById("myVideo").appendChild(videoDiv);
}
</script>

<div id="myVideo"></div> 

</body>
```

this is `createVideoDiv()`:

```
function createVideoDiv() {  
  var video = document.createElement("VIDEO");
  video.setAttribute('controls', '');
  video.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
  video.setAttribute('width', '100%');

  var source = document.createElement("SOURCE");
  source.setAttribute('src', getClickedVideo());
  source.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4');

  video.appendChild(source);

  return video;
}
```

and this is the `css`:

```
#contentVideo:fullscreen {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

The page opens, the video autoplays, it's filling the whole inner part of the browser. I still see the browser.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Becoming full screen should be done by one user action, click, tap, or etc.
It has a JS code of course, but wouldn't run automatically when pages loads, because browser prevents that unless user does something.
That is a good and maybe necessary feature in order to stop ads annoy people.

So, simply make a button or something and assign your function as onclick handler.

Answer (score 1):

As F.NiX stated try to addEventListener to the window, when user clicks or presses a button or some other user input event. Then inside the callback just call element.requestFullscreen() on the DOM element you want to go fullscreen. You can refer to this page for details: [MDN Fullscreen API docs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

For example, when user clicks somewhere on the page, the element will go fullscreen.

```js
window.addEventListener('mousedown', ()=>element.requestFullscreen(), {once:true});
```

I've added `{once:true}` simply to delete the listener once it is called so it doesn't slow down the page. You can remove it if you want to.